# XSLT not working as expected

Tags: xslt

I have an Xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <child>
    <gc>gc1Value</gc>
  </child>
  <child>child2Value</child>
  <child>
    <gc>gc2Value</gc>
    <gc>gc3Value</gc>
    <gc>
      <ggc>ggcValue</ggc>
      <ggc>ggcValue</ggc>
    </gc>
  </child>
</root>
```

and an Xslt file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <root>
      <xsl:for-each select="root/child">
        <xsl:if test=".!=''">
          <value>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </value>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:for-each select="root/child/gc">
          <xsl:if test=".!=''">
            <value>
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </value>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:for-each select="root/child/gc/ggc">
            <xsl:if test=".!=''">
              <value>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              </value>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
      </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm expecting to see this kind of result:

```
<root>
  <value>gc1Value</value>
  <value>child2Value</value>
  <value>gc2Value</value>
  <value>gc3Value</value>
  <value>ggcValue</value>
  <value>ggcValue</value>
</root>
```

but I'm getting this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <value>
    gc1Value
  </value>
  <value>child2Value</value>
  <value>
    gc2Value
    gc3Value

      ggcValue
      ggcValue

  </value>
</root>
```

I thought that by using `.` for the select this would only select the current node's value, but it appears to be getting the values from the children as well. What should I do instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in here:

```
    <xsl:if test="gc!=''">
      <value>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </value>
    </xsl:if>
```

"." will get the current node and all its children.

Use node::text() [ ie. select="text()" ]  if you only want the text. Also I would advise using 'string-length(node) != 0' and the likes instead of '',

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with your output.

```
     <value>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </value>
```

You have newline + whitespace + actual value + newline + whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

If the intention is to simply output all text nodes as **value** elements, you could take a more simplified approach that would work for any XML structure, regardless of element names.

Try this XSLT for example. This relies on the built-in template rule for an element, which just processes its child elements

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="text()">
      <value>
         <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </value>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should also give you your expected results.